# How to have Firefox open all internal links normally?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-tabs

How to have [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.com) open all internal links normally ?

- By “internal”, I mean the links that come from Firefox, the only other links being the links coming from other apps or from the OS.
- By “normally”, I mean opening the link in its tab.
- By “all”, I mean all, including “jumping” links — you know, these [rude](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WAI-WEBCONTENT-19990505/#tech-avoid-pop-ups) links with the non-standard attribute `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959136) from Mozilla support seems to be useful. Quoting from there. You need to set the values marked *italic*. Just checked with FF v.23.0.1/Windows.

> In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` and press Enter.
> Click the button promising to be careful.
> In the filter box, type or paste `link.o` and pause while the list is filtered.
> Double click these and set the value as desired:
>
> **(A) browser.link.open_newwindow**
>
> 3 = divert new window to a new tab (default) (checked*)
> 2 = allow link to open a new window (unchecked*)
> *1 = force new window into same tab*
>
> * First checkbox in Options > Tabs
>
> **(B) browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction - for links in Firefox tabs**
>
> *0 = apply the setting under (A) to ALL new windows (even script windows)*
> 2 = apply the setting under (A) to normal windows, but NOT to script windows with features (default)
> 1 = override the setting under (A) and always use new windows
>
> **(C) browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external - for links in other programs**
>
> -1 = apply the setting under (A) to external links (default)
> 3 = open external links in a new tab in the last active window
> 2 = open external links in a new window
> *1 = open external links in the last active tab replacing the current page*

Comment: I was going to set [the hidden pref *browser.link.open_newwindow*](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow). But I will not do that, because of [the stupid bug *469082* of Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469082).